# Утечка памяти в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобраться в чем корявость кода. Возможно написано не рационально. При работе в Google Chrome через 8-10 часов начинаются страшные зависания и пожирание памяти.
Скрипт по Json получает данные, данных не много , и через ajax обновляет их с интервалом в 5 секунд.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });
  setTimeout(getData, 5000);
});

/* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
function getData() {
  $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = +h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    $('table').empty();
    $('ul').empty();

    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('ul').append(
        '<tr><td><li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' MSK' + /*' ' + val.event + */ 
        '</td><td>' + val.region.replace("POV", "<b><font color\=\"FireBrick\">POV</font></b>").replace("SZ", "<b><font color\=\"darkmagenta\">SZ</font></b>").replace("SIB", "<b><font color\=\"Olive\">SIB</font></b>").replace("UG", "<b><font color\=\"MidnightBlue\">UG</font></b>") + 
        '</td><td>' + val.host + 
        '</td><td>' + val.type.replace("[", "<b>").replace("]", "</b>") + 
        '</td><td>' + val.info + 
        '</td><td>' + val.status.replace("0", "<img src=\"green.png\">").replace("1", "<img src=\"red.png\">") + 
        '</li></td></tr>'
      );
    });
    setTimeout(getData, 5000);
  });
}
```

Comment: Поступите классически. Закоментируйте максимально код, так что бы только запросы к серверу выполнялись (я бы начал коментировать начиная с строки `$('table').empty();` и до `setTimeout` (не включая её)). И посмотрел, воспроизводиться ли утечка.

Comment: Как проверять утечки не дожидаясь 8 часов? Через timeline в хроме?

Comment: а почему ты решил, что _страшные зависания и пожирание памяти._ - происходят именно в этом скрипте?

Comment: `Как проверять утечки не дожидаясь 8 часов` - ну кто знает, может проблема повторяется именно в определенное время, а 8 часов - это просто совпадение.

Comment: что у Вас с тагом `li`?

Comment: В каком плане с тегом li?

Comment: Почему бы не обойтись без jQuery? Возможно, косяк в нём. А ещё, конечно же, если данные обновляются нечасто, можно было бы воспользоваться чем-нибудь вроде mithril.js с его Virtual DOM, чтобы не пересоздавать все элементы каждый раз. Плюс была бы защита от инъекций.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin `li` открывается в одном `td`, а закрывается - в другом.

Comment: @DimaKuzmin "Как проверять утечки не дожидаясь 8 часов?" - Увеличить объем данных и уменьшить интервал их перезагрузки.

Comment: @Igor, это может просто показать **другую** ошибку

Comment: зачем вы отчищаете сначала `table`, а потом и `ul`, в которой находится `table` (судя из кода)?

Comment: Осталосся кусок от старого скрипта. Удалил. Спасибо за заметку.

Comment: <ul><tr><td><li> Кто так верстает? Оставьте или таблицу, или список.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery не служит экономии памяти. Когда вызывается `$('...').empty()` дочерние элементы, вполне вероятно не удаляются совсем (для браузера) - поэтому при большом количестве итераций лучше пользоваться другими способами модификации HTML.

Второе - жизнь страницы 8-10 часов обоснована только тогда, когда пользователь, не закрывая вкладку/браузер отходит от компьютера да долгое время - на иную жизнь страниц по 8-10 часов браузеры не рассчитывают. Под жизнью понимается активность скриптов, ajax-запросов, и.т.п. То есть - если страница открыта, но пользователь не активен: стопорить скрипты, утечек не будет. Поэтому можно вычислять активность пользователя:

```
$(document).on('mousemove keyup',function(){
  window.lastActivity = (new Date).valueOf();
});
```

И если, например, активности не было минуту - стопорить деятельность интервала:

```
function getData() {
   if ((new Date).valueOf() - window.lastActivity > 60*1000){
     setTimeout(getData, 1000);
     return;
   }
   ...
}
```

Тогда, если пользователь "объявится" - страница оживёт не позже чем через секунду. Это простой пример, правильнее учитывать ещё фокусировку/расфокусировку окна, событие скролла - но подход стандартный. Например мобильные браузеры сами стопорят работу JS на уровне ядра при сворачивании браузера, при смене вкладки: там следить за активностью незачем.

Answer (score 0):

может потому что ты создаешь timeout, но их не очищаешь с помощью clearTimeout? Попробуй что-то вроде этого

```js
var timeOut = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                cache: false
            });
            timeOut = setTimeout(getData, 5000);
        });

        /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
        function getData() {
            if (timeOut) {
                clearTimeout(timeOut);
                timeOut = null;
            }
            $.getJSON('api.php', function (data) {
                var d = new Date();
                var h = d.getHours();
                var m = d.getMinutes();
                var s = d.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = +h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
                $('table').empty();
                $('ul').empty();

                /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    $('ul').append('<tr><td><li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' MSK' + /*' ' + val.event + */ '</td><td>' + val.region.replace("POV", "<b><font color\=\"FireBrick\">POV</font></b>").replace("SZ", "<b><font color\=\"darkmagenta\">SZ</font></b>").replace("SIB", "<b><font color\=\"Olive\">SIB</font></b>").replace("UG", "<b><font color\=\"MidnightBlue\">UG</font></b>") + '</td><td>' + val.host + '</td><td>' + val.type.replace("[", "<b>").replace("]", "</b>") + '</td><td>' + val.info + '</td><td>' + val.status.replace("0", "<img src=\"green.png\">").replace("1", "<img src=\"red.png\">") + '</li></td></tr>');
                });
                timeOut = setTimeout(getData, 5000);
            });
        }
```

Comment: и теперь ссылка на таймаут дополнительно лежит и в переменной. `setTimeout`, это не `setInterval` **после** срабатывания - бесполезно выполнять `clear`